# Routh-Hurwitz for eigenvalues

Tags: ca.classical-analysis-and-odes, ds.dynamical-systems, cv.complex-variables

The Routh-Hurwitz criterion provides a convenient test, even for hand calculation, of whether a polynomial with real coefficients has all its  roots in the left half plane.  I'm wondering about a similar test for whether the eigenvalues of a real matrix lie in the LHP.  In principle, one could find the characteristic polynomial of the matrix and apply the Routh-Hurwitz test to this, but finding the characteristic polynomial of a matrix, even one of modest size, is not a convenient hand calculation.  Does anyone know of a more conveniently applied test for all the eigenvalues to lie in the LHP?

Comment: What does Gantmacher says about that ? His second volume is dedicated to such questions.

Comment: I have often wondered about this question as well. @Denis Serre - I don't believe Gantmacher addresses the matrix version of this question.

Answer (score 3):

The most convenient algebraic test for stability of a matrix $A$ known to humankind is to pick an arbitrary $Q>0$ and solve the matrix Lyapunov equation $A^T P + P A  + Q = 0$. All eigenvalues of $A$ have negative real part if and only if $P>0$.

Answer (score 0):

From Gershgorin's circle theorem (see Wikipedia) I believe it follows that a matrix $A = [A_{ij}]$ with real entries has eigenvalues with negative real part if 
\begin{equation}
A_{ii} + \sum_{j\neq i} |A_{ij}| < 0, \quad \forall i.
\end{equation}
This is of course just a sufficient criterion.

Answer (score 0):

I think this fits the bill:

http://books.google.ie/books?id=LeuNXB2bl5EC&q=routh-hurwitz#v=onepage&q=routh-hurwitz&f=true

Comment: This link is no longer working.

Answer (score -1):

No similar algebraic stability test for matices, it is well-known.

Comment: Would you mind editing your answer and providing references? This might be well-known for you, but not for us, and some insights would be great.